# How to show pdf in Android

Tags: android, pdf

I want to show a `pdf` file within my application. I have kept `pdf` file in my asset folder and i am using `itextpdf` 5.1.1 library. 
I am just trying to show the `pdf` using this library but not getting success. where as i 
am getting the `page numbers` of the `pdf` file using the code:

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getResources().getAssets().open("pp.pdf");           
PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader(inputStream);           
int pageNumber = pdfreader.getNumberOfPages();
```

Can anybody please help..   how to show pdf using itextpdf library.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Here Same question descussed  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108013/how-to-show-pdf-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi by using the following  code we can load the PDF.

```
String url = "http://marico.com/html/investor/pdf/annual_reports/ann_report_view_2010_11/Marico_Annual_Report_2010_11.pdf";
String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+url;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(googleDocsUrl ), "text/html");
 startActivity(intent);
```

If you want to load the pdf inside the web view then just write..

```
this.myWebView.loadUrl(googleDocsUrl);
```

Hope this work.

Answer (score 1):

iText is a library for creating PDFs, it is not a reader/renderer. Take a look at [DroidReader](http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/), which is based on [MuPdf](http://www.mupdf.com/). Also you can try some other libraries noted in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
    String url = "http://marico.com/html/investor/pdf/annual_reports/ann_report_view_2010_11/Marico_Annual_Report_2010_11.pdf";
   String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+url;
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(googleDocsUrl ), "text/html");
   startActivity(intent);
```

hi i used above code but in emulater it not showing.
it showing try to upgrade pdfviewr what i do please tell me